# How to create a vector with the variables to use in hclust

Tags: r, error-handling, verification, hclust

I'm using the hclust function in a large script applied to a df like in this example:

```
HClust <- hclust(d = dist(model.matrix(~-1 + A + B + C + D, df))^2, method = "centroid")
```

I would like to specify only once the variables in the df, eg. MgO, Zn, CaO... and when I call hclust() I would like to have them automatically.

I've tried creating a vector which will include the dataframe variables in the format that I will use for the hclust call. But the resulting dendrogram is not correct.

```
  vars_for_clust <- paste(colnames(df),"+")
```

which gives the following:

```
vars_for_clust
[1] "A+" "B+" "C+"
```

and used this vector in the hclust call:

```
  HClust <- hclust(d = dist(model.matrix(~-1 + vars_for_clust, df))^2, method = "centroid")
```

but something went wrong because even if it does not give an error, the resulting dendrogram is not correct (all the vertical lines are equal)

Thanks!!

Sample data in:
https://github.com/esteful/kaixo

Comment: can you add sample data?

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems here: 1. your use of `paste` and 2. your use of `vars_for_clust` as an argument to `model.matrix`.

To get what you need,  you should construct the entire formula as a string and then convert it to a formula - like this:

```
(FormString <- paste(c("~ -1", colnames(df)), collapse=" + "))
[1] "~ -1 + A + B + C"
HClust <- hclust(d = dist(model.matrix(as.formula(FormString), df))^2, method = "centroid")
```